# How to connect to remote HDFS

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs, remote-access

i am trying to connect to an HDFS instance running on a remote machine.

I am running eclipse on a windows machine and the HDFS is running on a Unix box. Here is what i have tried

```
         Configuration conf = new Configuration();
         conf.set("fs.defaultFS", "hdfs://remoteHostName:portNumber");
         DFSClient client = null;
         System.out.println("try");
         try 
         {
             System.out.println("trying");   
             client = new DFSClient(conf);

        System.out.println(client);
         } 
         catch (IOException e) {

             e.printStackTrace();
        }

         finally {
             if(client!=null)
                 try {
                    client.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


         }
```

but this gives me the following exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(Ljava/lang/Class;JLjava/net/InetSocketAddress;Lorg/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation;Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljavax/net/SocketFactory;ILorg/apache/hadoop/io/retry/RetryPolicy;Z)Lorg/apache/hadoop/ipc/VersionedProtocol;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:280)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:226)
```

by the way, i got the portNumber from the hdfs-site.xml on the remote machine

Is this approach correct?

Also, would it be easier to do this in Python?

**EDIT**

Note that i do have the Hadoop binaries unzipped on my windows and i have set the HADOOP_HOME environment variable accordingly. Could this be causing a problem?

Comment: Aside from following the example for connecting to hadoop from the hadoop or cloudera website, the error you are seeing can occur when some dependencies are missing. 
If you are using a project management tool like maven, if you could share your pom.xml that might help in narrowing down the missing dependency. Or if you are running this directory and providing the directory for the binaries in the path, then sharing what binaries are in that path can help. 
Ideally, you should have a hadoop-client-<version>.jar in your path or pom.xml.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Hadoop 2.6.0 Browsing filesystem Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29538908/hadoop-2-6-0-browsing-filesystem-java) for your specific problem.

Beyond that, you might want to consider using REST for remote interactions. Apache Knox can provide you with access to the remote cluster and shield your code from having to know cluster internals such as host:port, kerberos or not, etc. These things can change out from under your remote clients.